# How to store data to an object in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to store the form data into the an array(it is an array of objects) which is declared in controllers. Each time the form is submitted, the Form data in the format of an object should get appended in the array called `expenses`. The code is  -

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('expenseForm', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.expenses = [{
  exTitle: "",
  amount: "",
  typeOfShare: "",
  date: ""
 }];
 $scope.**submitExpense** = function (expenseInfo) {

 }
});
```

---

**expense.html**

```
<form class="clearBoth" ng-controller="expenseForm" ng-submit="submitExpense(expenseInfo)">
    <div class="expenseDesc" ng-model="expenseInfo">
        <div class="leftDesc">
            <div class="item">
                <label for="title">Expense Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="exTitle" name="title" ng-model="expenseInfo.exTitle"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label for="amount">Total Amount Spend</label>
                <input type="text" id="totAmt" name="amount" ng-model="expenseInfo.amount"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <label for="shareType">Type of Share</label>
                <select name="shareType" ng-model="expenseInfo.typeOfShare">
                    <option value="equal">Equal</option>
                    <option value="unequal">Unequal</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightDesc">
            <div class="item">
                <label for="date">Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" ng-model="expenseInfo.date"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="lowerSection">
            <div class="expenseTable clearBoth">
                <div class="tblHeader row">
                    <div class="sNo">SNo.</div>
                    <div class="email">Email</div>
                    <div class="name">Name</div>
                    <div class="share">Share</div>
                    <div class="paid">Paid</div>
                    <div class="owesTo">Owes To</div>
                    <div class="getsFrom">Gets From</div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tblBody">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="sNo">1</div>
                        <div class="email">gnehapk@gmail.com</div>
                        <div class="name">Neha</div>
                        <div class="share">700</div>
                        <div class="paid">500</div>
                        <div class="owesTo">200 to Sneha</div>
                        <div class="getsFrom"></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tblFooter clearBoth">
                    <button id="addMember">Add Member</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->

    </div> <!--end of expenseDesc-->
    <input type="submit" value="AddExpense" class="clearBoth" />
</form>
```

Here i am declaring a `expenseInfo` variable in the html page, which will contain all the details such as title, date etc. What should i write in **submitExpense** function so that this object gets appended in the **expenses** array?

Comment: `expenses.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expenseInfo))` (the parse and stringify are for making a copy)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `push` command:

```
 $scope.submitExpense = function (expenseInfo) {
    $scope.expenses.push(expenseInfo);
 }
```

see Demo in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1488/)</kbd>