# How do you store an object into scope

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering how to store an object into a scope. I am not sure if my syntax is correct. My objective is to setup up the data-binding on this edit page, and then store the edited object on the scope. But data won't get pushed into the array

```
$scope.editedRecord = function (editedExpensesInfo) {
        $scope.tempData.push(editedExpensesInfo)
    }
$scope.save = function() {

    WebApi.editData($scope.tempData);
};
```

TempData is my array in the service.

```
angular.module('app')

    .factory('WebApi', function () {

         var tempData = [];

        return{
        editData: function (data) {
                    return tempData = data;
                },
        }
    }
```

This is my edit form

```
    <!--Ion-nav-header-bar-->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack()">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>


    <!--ion-nav-side-menu-button-->
    <!--<ion-nav-buttons side="left">

        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>

    </ion-nav-buttons>-->
    <!--Content for Expenses page-->
    <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
        <div ng-controller="editExpensesDetailCtrl" ng-model="editedExpensesInfo">
            <form name="editExpensesDetailform"  ng-submit="editedRecord(editedExpensesInfo)>
 <label class="item item-input ">
                    <b class="input-label">Owner:</b>
                    {{data.owner}}
                </label>

                <label class="item item-input">
                    <b class="input-label">Receipt Date:</b>
                    <!--{{data.modifiedDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}-->
                    <input style="margin-left: 20%;" ng-model="editedExpensesInfo.newDate" type="date" placeholder="Date" required>
                </label>

                <!--<label class="item item-input">
                    <b class="input-label">Claim Type:</b>

                    {{data.claimType}}
                </label>-->

                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <b class="input-label">Claim Type:</b>
                    <select ng-model="editedExpensesInfo.newClaimType" required>
                        <option value="" title="Select Claim" selected disabled>Claim Type</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="claim in claimType" value="{{claim.value}}"
                                ng-selected="{{claim.value== claimType}}">
                            {{claim.value}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </label>

                <br />
                <!--Remarks Textfield-->
                <br />
                <b>Remarks:</b>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <!--<span style="margin-bottom:auto"> {{data.description}}</span>-->
                    <textarea ng-model="editedExpensesInfo.newDescription" rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Your remarks..." style="resize:none; border:solid 1px;"></textarea>
                </label>
            </form>
            <br />
            <a class="button button-positive" ng-click="save()">Save</a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your code. And make your question clearer. `But nothing seems to happen.` is vague.

Comment: Where did you call $scope.editedRecord? If you didn't call it then the data won't get pushed into the array.

Comment: @lcycool, I just have that editedRecord setting in my controller. How do I call it to make it work?

Comment: oh right, I have the called it in the <form ng-submit="editedRecord(editedExpensesInfo)">, I have just edited my code, but that still don't change anything

Comment: you are setting the variable on controller scope and trying to find it on service scope. how is that even possible.

Comment: Is there a way to do it? It is because I follow the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854762/how-to-store-data-to-an-object-in-angularjs to do it

Comment: So is your question basically "How to store an object in a service"? I'm having trouble understanding what your goal is here.

Comment: Hi Fisso, yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller function `editedRecord` is not getting called.

Check the [ngSubmit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) documentation.

You need to add a submit button. for example:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Edit" />
```

Hope this helps.